# Is a plate china?

Tags: vocabulary

I'm not talking about country, but porcelain. When people say:

> 'Be careful! That china vase is fragile!'

What does exactly china mean? My bilingual dictionary translated this as **porcelain plates**. I also googled china porcelain and this was one of the image that appeared:

[image]

Source: sharonlathanauthor.com

Now, my question, is it a common name for a thing made by clay or is it specifically a thing that's made by China (country)? I mean, for example I have these things, but they are made by Bulgaria, is it still called china?

Comment: So... a dictionary has told you it's porcelain ware from any country, and this image you found shows porcelain from Bulgaria. Looks to me you've done enough research to reach a conclusion. What doubts do you have? Not all turkeys come from Turkey, and you can get a Brazilian wax in any country in the world.

Comment: @gotube my doubt is in my country, this is called ceramics and I'm afraid if for example I want to buy these things when I say I want to buy a china vase, I refer to something different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"China porcelain" is called that because it was first made in China. The term is now generic and can be used regardless of the actual place of manufacture.

Answer (score 1):

In common usage, porcelain and china are the same thing, a specific type of cheap and durable ceramic, with the latter simply referring to where porcelain was first invented.

Fine china and bone china are similar ceramics but with slightly different processes and materials that make them lighter but also much more expensive and fragile than plain china.